# D3 rotation angle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have been trying to rotate an object in SVG on its axis, i have gotten it to work but the angle of rotation seems to jump to extremes . I have added an [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roug3/r7ezwkdp/) for it. Dragging the handle on the bottom a few pixels to the right gives an angle of "174.50767482860908" but dragging the handle on top instead of the angle decreasing just flips to a negative value say "-2.3372981369071644". I have been at it for some time and any assistance would be appretiated.

```
var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    data = {
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        rx: 100,
        ry: 50,
        angle: 0
    };

// Returns radians
function angleBetweenPoints(p1, p2) {
    if (p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] == p2[1])
        return Math.PI / 2;
    else
        return Math.atan2(p2[1] - p1[1], p2[0] - p1[0] );
}

function distanceBetweenPoints(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( p2[1] - p1[1], 2 ) + Math.pow( p2[0] - p1[0], 2 ) );
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 300);

var group = svg.append("svg:g").attr('id' , 'id123');


var handles = group.selectAll("circle")
        .data([
            {x:data.x, y:data.y + data.ry, name:"n"},
            {x:data.x, y:data.y - data.ry, name:"s"},
        ], function (d) { return d.name; })
        .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("r", 6.5)
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("drag", function (d) {
                // Resizing

                var exy = [d3.event.x, d3.event.y],
                    dxy = [data.x, data.y],
                    dist = distanceBetweenPoints(exy, dxy),
                    angle = data.angle + angleBetweenPoints(dxy, exy);
                switch(d.name) {
                    case "e":
                    case "w":
                        break;
                    case "s":
                    case "n":
                        angle += Math.PI/2;
                        break;
                };
                data.angle = angle;
                update();
            })
        );

var rect = group.append("svg:rect");

function toDegrees(rad) {
         rad = Number(rad) % (2*Math.PI);
        if (rad < -Math.PI)
            rad = rad % Math.PI + Math.PI;
        else if (rad > Math.PI)
            rad = rad % Math.PI - Math.PI;

    return rad * (180/Math.PI);
}

function update() {
    rect
        .attr("x", data.x - data.rx +5)
        .attr("y", data.y  - data.ry +5)
        .attr("width", (data.rx*2)-10)
        .attr("height", (data.ry*2)-10);

    document.getElementById("angle").innerHTML = toDegrees(data.angle);

    group.attr("transform", "rotate(" + toDegrees(data.angle) + "," + data.x + "," + data.y + ")");

}

update();
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here? What do you expect to happen that is not happening?

Comment: The problem is that the angle is supposed to gradually increase not jump across extremes

Comment: That's how [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) works. Actually your code gives correct values on top positions, but bottom positions fail. Notice, that there's a 360 deg jump from 179.99 ... to -179.99 ... when you move the mouse over BDC.

Comment: To fix the angle info, you've to remove all the code but the `return` statements from `angleBetweenPoints` and `toDegrees` functions (preserve the maths in those statements though). Then you can see the basic problem you have, which is that you're actually showing the angle between mouse and Y-axis, not the position of the element. You need to store the mouse's and element's position to different variables, and calculate only the change into mouse's position, and add the change to element's position.

Comment: thanks @Teemu , Appreciate the help.